# How to open SSH socks proxy at startup?

Tags: terminal, automator, ssh, proxy

I use remote socks proxies for occasions when I need an IP from various locations.  There is one that I use far more than any others, to the point that I would like a connection to be opened by default when my client machine boots.

Currently I have to open terminal, execute an `SSH -D` command, type in a password, and then the proxy is live.  I would really like to automate this at startup somehow, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  I'm intermediate with CLI stuff but a novice with shell scripting and so forth, so I really don't even know where to begin.

Is there an easy way to have this SSH connection start automatically at client startup?

So far in my searching for a solution, I have found this and am running as an automator workflow using the Run Shell Script module:

```
ip=aa.bb.cc.dd   #replace with your unix server's ip
username=yyyyyyyyyy #your ssh username
password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #your ssh password
command=ssh -D 2002     #what do you want to do with remote server
arguments=-Cq     #arguments for your command
expect -c 'spawn ssh $username@$ip ; expect password ; send "$password\n" ; interact'
```

It seems to work, in that Automator gives no errors and reports Workflow completed.  However the proxy is not accessible from a browser, so clearly something is wrong.

I'm using Mavericks, latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the arguments to the `ssh` command you are running, not to some variables:

```
ip=aa.bb.cc.dd   #replace with your unix server's ip
username=yyyyyyyyyy #your ssh username
password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx #your ssh password
command="ssh -D 2002"     #what do you want to do with remote server
arguments=-Cq     #arguments for your command
expect -c 'spawn $command $arguments $username@$ip ; expect password ; send "$password\n" ; interact'
```

Comment: Aha... so can I not just include $command in the final line?  Doing so isn't working for me... wondering why not?  `expect -c 'spawn $command $username@$ip ; expect password ; send "$password\n" ; interact'`

Comment: Sure, if it looks better to you

Comment: but Automator doesn't seem to like that... `(
  "-: line 3: -D: command not found",
  "can't read "command": no such variable",
  "    while executing",
  ""spawn $command $username@$ip "
"
)`

Comment: Maybe putting it into the `"` quotes?

Comment: Yep just had that exact same thought.  Automator no longer complains, however my proxy still does not function.  So close and yet...

Comment: so try to remove the `-q` if you will get some output.

Comment: No change... Automator output is empty `( "" )`

Comment: Additional clarification - the proxy does not work even if the command is direct without the variable - `expect -c 'spawn ssh -D 2003 $username@$ip ; expect password ; send "$password\n" ; interact'`